# The Linq Query Is Not Created

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class MergeTwoCSVFiles
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // See section Compiling the Code for information about the data files.
            string[] names = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\users\mypc\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects" + 
            @"\CustomJoinsLinq_cs\CustomJoinsLinq_cs\names.csv");
            string[] scores = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\users\mypc\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects" + 
            @"\CustomJoinsLinq_cs\CustomJoinsLinq_cs\scores.csv");

            // Merge the data sources using a named type.
            // You could use var instead of an explicit type for the query.
             IEnumerable<Student> queryNamesScores =
                 // Split each line in the data files into an array of strings.
                 from name in names
                 let x = name.Split(',')
                 from score in scores
                 let s = score.Split(',')
                 // Look for matching IDs from the two data files.
                 where x[2] == s[0]
                 // If the IDs match, build a Student object.
                 select new Student()
                 {
                     FirstName = x[0],
                     LastName = x[1],
                     ID = Convert.ToInt32(x[2]),
                     ExamScores = (from scoreAsText in s.Skip(1)
                               select Convert.ToInt32(scoreAsText)).
                               ToList()
                 };

             // Optional. Store the newly created student objects in memory
             // for faster access in future queries
             List<Student> students = queryNamesScores.ToList();

             foreach (var student in students)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("The average score of {0} {1} is {2}.",
                 student.FirstName, student.LastName, student.ExamScores.Average());
             }

            /*foreach (var item in scores)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }*/

            //Keep console window open in debug mode
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Student
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<int> ExamScores { get; set; }
    }
```

Hi Guys
Please when I run the above program, only Press any key to exit. displays, which is the exit of the program. It is supposed to display the outcome, of the execution of the query, but it doesn't. 
On debug mode, noticed the data sources gets obtained (performed a for each, which is commented out above, on one of the data sources, and it works fine), but the query, doesn't get created and therefore doesn't get executed.
The scores array of string data source contains 12 lines on the scores.csv file, though adding the scores array of strings  to watch window, on debug mode, says the array is of length 14. Don't know if these has anything to do with it.  
Both classes are on the same namespace, which I didn't show here
Please can someone be of help. I am using visual studio 2017   
Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "query doesn't get created?" Which query? How do you know this? For me it is absolutely unclear what is your problem now.

Comment: Of course the query is getting created..There's something wrong in your join or in your data that's causing no data to be returned.

Comment: Make sure the files contain the correct data.  The problem appears with the line :  "where x[2] == s[0]".  The 3rd column in the names file is not matching the first column in the score file.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev  while debubbing, while stepping over, when I get to the creation of the query, it steps over it. doesn't step through it

Comment: There may be extra spaces in the data.  I would try following : where x[2].Trim() == s[0].Trim().  You also should use equals : x[2].Trim() equals s[0].Trim()

Comment: "// Look for matching IDs from the two data files." That sounds like you should be using a join...

Comment: @jdweng Cheers mate. You're a star. That did it. x[2].Trim() == s[0].Trim()